# read_replicas_mode & replica_count variables are not expected in google_redis_instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-memorystore

We have used the memory store module for spinning up a redis instance on GCP. However, at a later stage, when we try to enable READ REPLICA via terraform it doesn't accept.

References:

https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-memorystore

```
module "memorystore_replica" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/memorystore/google"
  version = "4.0.0"

  redis_version           = "REDIS_6_X"
  name                    = "${module.project.project_name}-redisreadreplica-${module.locations.region_codes[var.region]}-instance"
  project                 = module.project.project_id
  region                  = var.region
  authorized_network      = local.vpc
  connect_mode            = var.redis_connection_type
  memory_size_gb          = var.redis_memory_size_gb
  transit_encryption_mode = "DISABLED"
  labels                  = var.labels
  replica_count           = 2
  read_replicas_mode      = "READ_REPLICAS_ENABLED"
}
```

```
resource "google_redis_instance" "default" {
  depends_on = [module.enable_apis]

  project        = var.project
  name           = var.name
  tier           = var.tier
  memory_size_gb = var.memory_size_gb
  connect_mode   = var.connect_mode

  region                  = var.region
  location_id             = var.location_id
  alternative_location_id = var.alternative_location_id

  authorized_network = var.authorized_network

  redis_version     = var.redis_version
  redis_configs     = var.redis_configs
  display_name      = var.display_name
  reserved_ip_range = var.reserved_ip_range

  labels = var.labels

  auth_enabled = var.auth_enabled

  transit_encryption_mode = var.transit_encryption_mode
}
```

```
Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 357, in module "memorystore_replica":
│  357:   replica_count           = 2
│ 
│ An argument named "replica_count" is not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 358, in module "memorystore_replica":
│  358:   read_replicas_mode      = "READ_REPLICAS_ENABLED"
│ 
│ An argument named "read_replicas_mode" is not expected here
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Where is your code in which you use the module?

Comment: What is the provider version being loaded when Terraform run?

Comment: @mino  Below providers were loaded while terraform run.


Terraform v0.14.9
Initializing plugins and modules...

google provider : 3.86.0 & 3.90.1

Comment: @krish checking the changelog of the provider https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md you will need to upgrade the provider to 4.3 or 4.16

Comment: Furthermore, the module itself needs to be >= 4.4 to support replica_count.

Comment: Thanks @mino Appreciate you responding. Perhaps I have already tried with updating the provider and module. For some reason, It's unable to download the versions.

Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
│ hashicorp/google: no available releases match the given constraints >=
│ 3.43.0, >= 3.50.0, ~> 3.53, >= 3.58.0, < 4.0.0, >= 4.10.0, 4.16.0, <
│ 5.0.0

```
 required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "4.16.0"
    }
```

I have tried with >= 4.20 as well.

Comment: Check your provider constraints across your tf files. Looks like you have multiple constraints, ~>3.53 and <4.0.0, which prevent from upgrading.

Comment: Yes @mino we have multiple constraints with "~>3.53 and <4.0.0" in different modules used with in the main.tf code. However, I was thinking the actual "versions.tf" from parent configuration will take the precedence from the modules "versions.tf" file. But it is not! Is there a way that actual versions.tf from main configuration takes the precedence and downloads the binaries?

Comment: @krish I doubt there is way to define precedence for version constraint in Terraform. Ref. https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/version-constraints#version-constraint-behavior

What you could do, based on recommendation from the same reference link above, is relax the child module provider constraint with ">=", while in the parent module a more sensitive version boundaries with "~>".